# Removing or overwriting a component from Windsor Container

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm trying to accomplish a seemingly super simple thing: from my unit test I want to replace the type being resolved with a mock/fake object.

For example: the xml config states that a component of the service IInterface should resolve to ClassA. That's fine, but from my unit test I want the type to resolve to FakeClassA instead. I can't use container.AddComponent for this, since there "is a component already registered for the given key ...".

Comment: See also: How are components removed with Castle 3.0? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501209/how-are-components-removed-with-castle-3-0

Answer (score 4):

IKernel has a [RemoveComponent](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/manual/mktypedocs/Generated_IKernel.html#IKernel_Methods19) method.

But for unit tests it's recommended that you don't use the container at all, or if the test setup gets too dense because of dependencies, use an [AutoMockingContainer](http://blog.eleutian.com/CommentView,guid,762249da-e25a-4503-8f20-c6d59b1a69bc.aspx).

[Here's](https://github.com/codechip/rhino-tools/tree/master/testing) another (more updated) implementation.

Comment: RemoveComponent states "Returns true if the specified component was found and could be removed (i.e. no other component depends on it)". But what if we dont care if something else depends upon it, as we are going to replace it in the next line of code.

Comment: You can't. Removing components from the container is *not* a normal usage in Windsor.

Comment: Mauricio Scheffer: You have a dead link

Comment: @kappasims : I did fix it back in '09 but it seems the repo was deleted. Fixed again. Also, please instead of just saying "still dead"  post a new repo, thanks.

Comment: RemoveComponent method has been removed From Windsor Castle 3

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Why it is not normal to remove components from windsor? Also, is it quite a generic statement applicable to all IoC containers like Unity, autofac etc? Generally we register all the dependencies at the start-up of the application. I'm needing this registration/de-registration of dependencies only in the case of unit test cases which run one after the other.

Comment: @RasikBihariTiwari Yes, this generalizes to all containers. IoC containers are bad enough as they are. If you start removing components you're making things even more mutable so harder to reason about.